# Black Aravos on Succos

Tags: halacha, sukkot, agriculture, color, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I have noticed some people using arovos which turned completely black towards the end of Yom Tov. When discussing arovos, the halacha mentions the importance of the green color, since it shows that it is not dried out (which can be a problem if it's completely dry).

The black aravos has no green color which the halacha speaks of, but it's not dry at all -- the leaves look exactly as they did before. What halachic authorities discuss this, and is it permissible to use?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Aravot

> The Mishna (33b) writes that a dry aravah is disqualified, while a
>   withered one is valid. The Rif (16a), Rambam (8:1), and Rosh (3:13)
>   all codify this Mishna as halacha. To clarify the boundary described
>   by the Mishna, Rambam explains that an aravah is valid as long as it
>   is not completely dry. Tur and Shulchan Aruch (647:2) codify this as
>   the halacha. Mishna Brurah (647:7) and Chazon Ovadia (p. 317) clarify
>   that an aravah is disqualified once a majority of its leaves have
>   become dried out. Shaar Hatziyun (647:6) quotes Bikkurei Yaakov, who
>   says that to be considered dried out an aravah must lose all of its
>   green color. Chazon Ovadia, however, says that the aravah must turn
>   white.

Comment: I know this already, what's the din of black?

Comment: @sam Second to last sentence.

Comment: So acc to the Bikkurei Yaakov its pasul and Chacham Ovadia its kosher?

Comment: It seems to me that the second-to-last sentence of your quotation refers to a color change as a necessary but insufficient criterion for driedness. Surely a spraypainted _arava_ wouldn't therefore be considered dry!